# Python indent error

Tags: python

I every time get a indent error with this code :

```
    if resulttaglist[1].childNodes[0].toxml() == 0:
    sys.exit
else:
    subdomaintaglist = doc.getElementsByTagName('subdomain')
    subdomain = subdomaintaglist[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
        maindomaintaglist = doc.getElementsByTagName('DOMAIN')
        maindomain = maindomaintaglist[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
    domain =  subdomain + '.' + maindomain
    usertaglist = doc.getElementsByTagName('USER')
    user = usertaglist[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
        docroot, yip, alias = createvhosts.getvars(domain)
        serverip = createvhosts.getmainip()
                if yip == serverip:
                    createvhosts.writeconfshared(user, domain, docroot, yip, alias)
                else:
                    createvhosts.writeconfded(user, domain, docroot, yip, alias)
        proc = subprocess.Popen("/etc/init.d/nginx restart > /dev/null 2>&1", shell=True)
```

Everytime i tried to correct it doesn't work, can anyone can say to me what is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You have mixed tabs and spaces. Use all tabs, or all spaces; I recommend all spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if resulttaglist[1].childNodes[0].toxml() == 0:
    sys.exit()
else:
    subdomaintaglist = doc.getElementsByTagName('subdomain')
    subdomain = subdomaintaglist[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
    maindomaintaglist = doc.getElementsByTagName('DOMAIN')
    maindomain = maindomaintaglist[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
    domain =  subdomain + '.' + maindomain
    usertaglist = doc.getElementsByTagName('USER')
    user = usertaglist[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
    docroot, yip, alias = createvhosts.getvars(domain)
    serverip = createvhosts.getmainip()
    if yip == serverip:
        createvhosts.writeconfshared(user, domain, docroot, yip, alias)
    else:
        createvhosts.writeconfded(user, domain, docroot, yip, alias)
    proc = subprocess.Popen("/etc/init.d/nginx restart > /dev/null 2>&1", shell=True)
```

Ensure your editor saves only spaces OR tabs, but not both. My personal preference is spaces.

Comment: Thanks, this is working, SublimeText was mixing spaces and tabs.

Comment: @RobotChief In SublimeText, if you highlight a block of code, tabs look like little dashes, and spaces look like little periods. You can also set it so that the tab button inserts spaces, not the tab stop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up tabs and spaces. if i am not wrong the indentation on starting if /else is incorrect and it is causing more bad indenting.
try this:-

```
if resulttaglist[1].childNodes[0].toxml() == 0:
    sys.exit
else:
    subdomaintaglist = doc.getElementsByTagName('subdomain')
    subdomain = subdom.........
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the existing 7-year-old answers and comments.